# SwiftUI: Passing an environmentObject to a sheet causes update problems

Tags: swiftui

If you want to pass an `@EnvironmentObject` to a View presented as a sheet, you'll notice that this sheet gets recreated every single time any `@Published` property in the `@EnvironmentObject` is updated.

Minimum example that demonstrates the problem:

```swift
import SwiftUI

class Store: ObservableObject {
  @Published var name = "Kevin"
  @Published var age = 38
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: Store
  @State private var showProfile = false

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Hello, \(store.name), you're \(store.age) years old")
      Button("Edit profile") {
        self.showProfile = true
      }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showProfile) {
      ProfileView()
        .environmentObject(self.store)
    }
  }
}

struct ProfileView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: Store
  @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Hello, \(store.name), you're \(store.age) years old")
      Button("Change age") {
        self.store.age += 1
      }
    }
  }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  init() {
    print("HERE")
  }
}
```

If you run this code, you'll notice that "HERE" gets logged every single time you press the button in the sheet, meaning that the `ViewModel` got recreated. This can be a huge problem as you might imagine, I expect the ViewModel to not get recreated but retain its state. It's causing huge problems in my app.

As far as I am aware, what I am doing in my code is the normal way to pass the `@EnvironmentObject` to a sheet. Is there a way to prevent the `ProfileView` from getting recreated any time something in the `Store` changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the **view** gets recreated when a state variable changes. And in your view you instantiate the viewModel as ViewModel().

Try passing the observed object as a param and it won't hit "HERE" anymore:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: Store
  @State private var showProfile = false
  @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Hello, \(store.name), you're \(store.age) years old")
      Button("Edit profile") {
        self.showProfile = true
      }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showProfile) {
      ProfileView(viewModel: self.viewModel)
        .environmentObject(self.store)
    }
  }
}

struct ProfileView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: Store
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Hello, \(store.name), you're \(store.age) years old")
      Button("Change age") {
        self.store.age += 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You wrote: `Try passing the observed object as a param...`, Does this mean that for a `.sheet(..) { SubView() }` in SwiftUI you cannot use @EnvironmentObjects inside the sheet's `SubView` ?? What if you have a complex View-Hierarchy and the View that calls the `sheet` in the first place, itself, has several parent-Views updating the EnvironmentObject eventually ? I don't want to pass binding-Parameters throughout the entire view-hierarchy, just because .sheet can't deal with @EnvironmentObjects. Or can you make an example with a complex view-Hierarchy and how this would work what you suggest ?

Comment: I have to agree that the intended use of @EnviornmentObject is to enable the view hierarchy to contain a single instance of the state stored in the ObservedObject. However, this is not the case in the sheet scenario. Is this a bug? Have you found a workaround? Passing a parameter everywhere is not only cumbersome to implement, but also defeats the purpose of having the environmentobject at ll in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If your Deployment Target is iOS14 and above, have you tried replacing `@ObservedObject` with `@StateObject` in `ProfileView`? This will help in keeping the state, it will only be created once, even if the Model View instantiaton happens inside the View's body.

Answer (score -2):

A very nice article about this issue [can be found her](https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-and-the-missing-environment-object-1a4bf8913ba7).

Comment: This article is _not_ about the same issue the OP is having. (Article is about crshing/missing environment objects for sheets/new vier hierarchies; OPs issue is that views and associated view models are being re-created when an environment object changes).